# got an error at __geo_interface__ geopandas choropleth map, anyone know?

Tags: python, geopandas, choropleth, geopy

```
area_sqkm = pd.Series(prov1.geometry.to_crs(epsg=32654).area / 10**6, name='area_sqkm')
stats = penduduk.join(area_sqkm)

# Add density (per square kilometer) of each prefecture
stats['density'] = stats["density_2019"] / stats["area_sqkm"]
print(stats)
prov1.to_crs(epsg=4326)
map1 = folium.Map(location=[-5.135399, 119.423790], zoom_start=5)

# Add a heatmap to the base map
for idx, row in mcd.iterrows():
    Marker([row['latitude'], row['longitude']]).add_to(map1)

# Population
Choropleth(geo_data=prov1['geometry'].__geo_interface__,
           data=stats["density"],
           key_on='featur.id',
           fill_color='YlGnBu',
           legend_name='Kepadatan Penduduk per 2019').add_to(map1)
```

> Choropleth(geo_data=prov1['geometry'].**geo_interface**,
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get

the map can works fine if i delete area formula

Comment: Please don't put all the text of the question in the title, write a short and informative title instead and give context and details in the body of the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more tips.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.